# How to fix "Segmentation fault" while printing string of struct?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, qsort

I wrote a code that stores details of persons in a struct which has a dynamically allocated array of pointers (pointing to structures). These structs are sorted via qsort and should be printed afterwards, but it displays "segmentation fault" right before printing. I assume the problem lies within the printf function and I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me what I have done wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 2
#define COUNT_OF(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(0[x])) //length of arrays at compile time

struct Person {
char firstname[64];
char lastname[64];
int age;
};

int Person_cmp_firstname(const void* x, const void* y) {
    struct Person *ix = (struct Person *)x;
    struct Person *iy = (struct Person *)y;
    return strcmp(ix->firstname, iy->firstname); 
    }


int Person_cmp_lastname(const void* x, const void* y ) {
    struct Person *ix = (struct Person *)x;
    struct Person *iy = (struct Person *)y;
    return strcmp(ix->lastname, iy->lastname); 
}
int Person_cmp_age(const void* x, const void* y) {
    struct Person *px = (struct Person *) x;
    struct Person *py = (struct Person *) y;
    return px->age - py->age;
}

int main(){;
    int choice;
    struct Person *P[10];
    printf("\t***PROGRAM TO SORT PERSONS***\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        P[i] = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
        printf("Firstname: ");
        scanf("%s", P[i]->firstname);
        printf("Lastname: ");
        scanf("%s", P[i]->lastname);
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &P[i]->age);
        printf("\t***NEXT PERSON***\n\n");
    }
    do{
        printf("\n\t***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***\n\n\tBy firstname: 1\n\tBy lastname: 2\n\tBy age: 3\n\tExit Program: 4\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("\t***SORTING BY FIRSTNAME...***\n\n");
                qsort(P, COUNT_OF(P), sizeof(struct Person), Person_cmp_firstname);
                printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
                for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n", P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\t***SORTING BY LASTNAME...***\n\n");
                qsort(P, COUNT_OF(P), sizeof(struct Person ), Person_cmp_lastname);
                printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
                for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n", P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\t***SORTING BY AGE...***\n\n");
                qsort(P, COUNT_OF(P), sizeof(struct Person), Person_cmp_age);
                printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
                for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n",P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("\t***EXITING PROGRAM***\n\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    free(P[j]);
                }
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("\t***INVALID OPTION***\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: As I see it, `COUNT_OF(P)` is 10. But you've only initialized 3 of the array entries. So I expect `qsort` to crash and burn.

Comment: Yeah, that could be an issue.  Get rid of the magic numbers and use a define for the length of your array and the condition on your loops.

Comment: Use a debugger to find the line that causes the segfault and update the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a large number of problems, all stemming from your incorrect handling of your *array of pointers*:

```
    struct Person *P[10];
```

When you declare `P` above, you have an array of 10 pointers, NOT 10 `struct Person`. Your allocation, `P[i] = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));` is fine, but See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

You then incorrectly use `COUNT_OF(x)` to set your loop limits (after hardcoding the 1st to `3`) which leaves you attempting to `qsort` and `free` elements `3-9` that are neither allocated or initialized leading to *Undefined Behavior*. (your SegFault can occur anywhere)

Your `qsort` compare functions are wrong. They are off by one-level-of-indirection. You are sorting `P` which is an *array of pointers*. Since `qsort` passes a *pointer-to-element* to your compare function (remember your elements are *pointers* not struct), `qsort` is passing a *pointer-to-pointer-to-struct* as parameters to your compare function. Therefore your compare functions need to provide an additional level of indirection in the type of variable the `const void *` parameters are converted to. For example:

```
int Person_cmp_firstname(const void* x, const void* y) {
    struct Person * const *ix = x;
    struct Person * const * iy = y;
    return strcmp((*ix)->firstname, (*iy)->firstname); 
}


int Person_cmp_lastname(const void* x, const void* y ) {
    struct Person * const *ix = x;
    struct Person * const *iy = y;
    return strcmp((*ix)->lastname, (*iy)->lastname); 
}

int Person_cmp_age(const void* x, const void* y) {
    struct Person * const *px = x;
    struct Person * const *py = y;
    return ((*px)->age > (*py)->age) - ((*px)->age < (*py)->age);
}
```

(**note:** since the parameters are `void*` there is no need to cast the assignments within each compare function. Also **note:** a subtraction of conditionals is used to avoid potential for overflow, e.g. `(a > b) - (a < b)` rather than just `a - b` for `age`)

In the remainder of your code, you need a counter to keep track of the number of elements filled, and use that counter as to pass to `qsort` and to print the sorted arrays (and `free` the pointers when done). A simple `n` counter is used below, e.g.

```
 int main(){;
    int choice, i, n;
    struct Person *P[10];
    printf("\t***PROGRAM TO SORT PERSONS***\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        P[i] = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
        printf("Firstname: ");
        scanf("%s", P[i]->firstname);
        printf("Lastname: ");
        scanf("%s", P[i]->lastname);
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &P[i]->age);
        printf("\t***NEXT PERSON***\n\n");
    }
    n = i;   /* saves the number of filled struct as n */
    ...
                qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_firstname);
                for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n",
                           P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
            ...
            case 4:
                printf("\t***EXITING PROGRAM***\n\n");
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    free(P[i]);
                }
                exit(0);
```

Now your code will work.

Putting it altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 2
#define COUNT_OF(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x)) //length of arrays at compile time

struct Person {
    char firstname[64];
    char lastname[64];
    int age;
};

int Person_cmp_firstname(const void* x, const void* y) {
    struct Person * const *ix = x;
    struct Person * const * iy = y;
    return strcmp((*ix)->firstname, (*iy)->firstname); 
}

int Person_cmp_lastname(const void* x, const void* y ) {
    struct Person * const *ix = x;
    struct Person * const *iy = y;
    return strcmp((*ix)->lastname, (*iy)->lastname); 
}

int Person_cmp_age(const void* x, const void* y) {
    struct Person * const *px = x;
    struct Person * const *py = y;
    return ((*px)->age > (*py)->age) - ((*px)->age < (*py)->age);
}

int main(){;
    int choice, i, n;
    struct Person *P[10];
    printf("\t***PROGRAM TO SORT PERSONS***\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        P[i] = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
        printf("Firstname: ");
        scanf("%s", P[i]->firstname);
        printf("Lastname: ");
        scanf("%s", P[i]->lastname);
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &P[i]->age);
        printf("\t***NEXT PERSON***\n\n");
    }
    n = i;
    do{
        printf("\n\t***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***\n\n\tBy firstname: 1\n\tBy lastname: 2\n\tBy age: 3\n\tExit Program: 4\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("\t***SORTING BY FIRSTNAME...***\n\n");
                qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_firstname);
                printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
                for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n", P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\t***SORTING BY LASTNAME...***\n\n");
                qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_lastname);
                printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
                for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n", P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\t***SORTING BY AGE...***\n\n");
                qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_age);
                printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
                for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                    printf( "Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n",P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age );
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("\t***EXITING PROGRAM***\n\n");
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    free(P[i]);
                }
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("\t***INVALID OPTION***\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/person_struct
        ***PROGRAM TO SORT PERSONS***

Firstname: Porky
Lastname: Pig
Age: 83
        ***NEXT PERSON***

Firstname: Daffy
Lastname: Duck
Age: 93
        ***NEXT PERSON***

Firstname: Mickey
Lastname: Mouse
Age: 100
        ***NEXT PERSON***


        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

2
        ***SORTING BY LASTNAME...***

        ***DONE***

Firstname: Daffy        | Lastname: Duck        | Age: 93
Firstname: Mickey       | Lastname: Mouse       | Age: 100
Firstname: Porky        | Lastname: Pig | Age: 83

        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

3
        ***SORTING BY AGE...***

        ***DONE***

Firstname: Porky        | Lastname: Pig | Age: 83
Firstname: Daffy        | Lastname: Duck        | Age: 93
Firstname: Mickey       | Lastname: Mouse       | Age: 100

        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

4
        ***EXITING PROGRAM***
```

(**note:** your input routine is horribly fragile and you fail to check the **return** of every `scanf`, further inviting *Undefined Behavior* with the slip of a single keystroke. Always ***validate*** Every user-input and Every allocation)

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/person_struct
==2078== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2078== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2078== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2078== Command: ./bin/person_struct
==2078==
        ***PROGRAM TO SORT PERSONS***

Firstname: John
Lastname: Wayne
Age: 91
        ***NEXT PERSON***

Firstname: Jane
Lastname: Doe
Age: 101
        ***NEXT PERSON***

Firstname: Mickey
Lastname: Mouse
Age: 99
        ***NEXT PERSON***


        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

1
        ***SORTING BY FIRSTNAME...***

        ***DONE***

Firstname: Jane | Lastname: Doe | Age: 101
Firstname: John | Lastname: Wayne       | Age: 91
Firstname: Mickey       | Lastname: Mouse       | Age: 99

        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

2
        ***SORTING BY LASTNAME...***

        ***DONE***

Firstname: Jane | Lastname: Doe | Age: 101
Firstname: Mickey       | Lastname: Mouse       | Age: 99
Firstname: John | Lastname: Wayne       | Age: 91

        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

3
        ***SORTING BY AGE...***

        ***DONE***

Firstname: John | Lastname: Wayne       | Age: 91
Firstname: Mickey       | Lastname: Mouse       | Age: 99
Firstname: Jane | Lastname: Doe | Age: 101

        ***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***

        By firstname: 1
        By lastname: 2
        By age: 3
        Exit Program: 4

4
        ***EXITING PROGRAM***

==2078==
==2078== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2078==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2078==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 396 bytes allocated
==2078==
==2078== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2078==
==2078== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2078== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.