# do block properly break out infinite loop

Tags: c

this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662680/15603477 ) answer is very good. while trying to replicate it. I found that if you type some wrong input(other than 1,2,3,4), it will be an infinite loop. I guess that mean in default part, it cannot break.
How to properly refactor it to make it not infinite loop when you type the wrong input.

```
do {
    printf("\n\t***CHOOSE HOW TO SORT***\n\n\tBy firstname: 1\n\tBy lastname: 2\n\tBy age: 3\n\tExit Program: 4\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        printf("\t***SORTING BY FIRSTNAME...***\n\n");
        qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_firstname);
        printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n", P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age);
        }
        break;
        
        case 2:
        printf("\t***SORTING BY LASTNAME...***\n\n");
        qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_lastname);
        printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n", P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age);
        }
        break;
        
        case 3:
        printf("\t***SORTING BY AGE...***\n\n");
        qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, Person_cmp_age);
        printf("\t***DONE***\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Firstname: %s\t| Lastname: %s\t| Age: %d\n",P[i]->firstname, P[i]->lastname, P[i]->age);
        }
        break;
        
        case 4:
        printf("\t***EXITING PROGRAM***\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            free(P[i]);
        }
        exit(0);
        
        default:
        printf("\t***INVALID OPTION***\n\n");
        break;
    }
} while (1);
```

---

update:

So far what I come from. add new variable count, begin with 0. then

```
...
default:
            printf("\t***INVALID OPTION***\n\n");
            count = count + 2;
            break;
        }
    }while(count < 2);
```

Comment: The code should test that the `scanf()` read a value, and do something other than run the `switch` statement if it does not.  The `default` case should consider prompting again, or at least state "please try again".  Especially while debugging, the default case should probably report the invalid value (`printf("Invalid option value %d; please try again\n", choice);` for example). If the `scanf()` fails to interpret the number, you should probably gobble up the rest of the input line.  All that SHOUTING in the messages is tiresome — don't use all caps without good reason.

Comment: And if you don't want an infinite loop, count the number of consecutive invalid choices and terminate the loop/program after some (fairly small) threshold such as 3 or 5 tries.  Include an appropriate apologetic message for not understanding what they've been busy typing.

Comment: There are multiple possible solutions, including additional variables to control the loop, putting the loop into a function and returning from it, add extra checks on the input with an `if`, ... Experiment and see what looks best to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually situations, where the `goto` label has a valid use. Usually `goto` is hated. But it is exactly what you need.

```
int main() {
    do {
        ...
        switch (choice) {
        ...
        default:
            printf("\t***INVALID OPTION***\n\n");
            goto invalid_input_found;
        }
    } while (1);
invalid_input_found:
    handle_error();
}
```

Your idea with a variable is great too, but an integer that you increment by 2 is a bit confusion. Maybe use a boolean value from `stdbool.h` for readability.

```
#include<stdbool.h>

int main() {
    bool run_loop = true;
    do {
        ...
        switch (choice) {
        ...
        default:
            printf("\t***INVALID OPTION***\n\n");
            run_loop = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (run_loop);
    handle_error();
}
```